Apple Watch: Stop Watch Background is Showing as Light Since Update
The stopwatch app on my apple watch series 8 is showing with a light background ever since I updated.
It used to have a black background.
Are we stuck with this?
Doesn't seem to be a way to get the dark background back from googling.
I have my phone on dark mode but it seems the apple watch doesn't have a light/dark mode.
Everything apart from the stop watch has a dark background.
My watch face is activity digital.

So far as I can tell, there's no way to change it at all. I use the timer function frequently and it has changed to a pleasing tangerine colored background.
You can, however, give Apple some feedback here.

Oh thank you, that is a useful workaround, I'll mention it to apple but I doubt they'll do anything
